# Playframework 2.6 [Java]: How to test a controller

Tags: java, playframework

I have a problem with testing my controller in my application.

First, I have a `Person` class:

```
public class Person extends Model {

    @Id
    public UUID id;
    public static final Finder<UUID , Person> find = new Finder<>(Person.class);

    @Constraints.Required
    @Constraints.MinLength(0)
    @Constraints.MaxLength(25)
    public String name;

    @Constraints.Required
    @Constraints.MinLength(0)
    @Constraints.MaxLength(25)
    public String lastname;

    @Constraints.Required
    @Constraints.Min(0)
    public int age;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
    List<ArticleVersion> version = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

And then my `PersonController` with the use of `@inject` in the body of the class:

```
public class PersonController extends Controller {


public FormFactory formFactory = null;

@Inject
public PersonController(FormFactory formFactory) {
    this.formFactory = formFactory;
}


public Result createPerson(){
    final Form<Person> form = formFactory.form(Person.class).bindFromRequest();
    if (form.hasErrors()) {
        return badRequest(form.errorsAsJson());
    }

    Person person = form.get();
    person.save();

    return created(Json.toJson(person));

}

public Result getPerson(String id){
    Person person = Person.find.byId(UUID.fromString(id));
    if (person == null) {
        return notFound("Person not found");
    }

    return ok(Json.toJson(person));
 }
}
```

And I want to test for example the createPerson method, but I don't know which testing method should I use and how. I tried look on some tutorials from Play Framework website but it didn't help me much. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I use a Scala trait to test the controllers in scalatest.

```scala
import java.util

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
import org.scalatestplus.play.guice.GuiceOneAppPerSuite
import play.mvc.{Http, Result}
import play.test.Helpers

/**
  * Access the Play server as an API using HTTP requests over a test server.
  */
trait APIServer extends FlatSpec with GuiceOneAppPerSuite
{
    /**
      * Track session values.
      */
    var session: Http.Session = new Http.Session(new util.HashMap[String, String]())

    /**
      * Execute a request to the server.
      *
      * @param uri     The path of the request
      * @param method  The HTTP method
      * @param request The request data as JsonNode
      * @return The result as a Play Result object
      */
    def request(uri: String, method: String, request: Option[JsonNode]): Result =
    {
        val req: Http.RequestBuilder = Helpers.fakeRequest(method, uri).session(session)

        if (request.isDefined)
        {
            req.bodyJson(request.get)
        }

        Helpers.route(this.app.asJava, req)
    }

}
```

Comment: But i need answer in Java (anyway, thanks for answer)

Comment: I also think it's ridiculous to test using ScalaTest while developing using Java. Let's hope there is a proper way in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Play Test Helpers, you could test the whole route in this way:

```java
import org.junit.Test;
import play.test.TestBrowser;

import static play.test.Helpers.*;

public class IntegrationTest
{

    @Test
    public void test(){
        running(fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase()), () -> {
            final TestBrowser testBrowser = testBrowser();
            testBrowser.goTo("/api/call/");
            assert(testBrowser.pageSource().equals("API response"));
        });
    }
}
```